# Can Windows ReadFile returns success without reading everything you asked for?

Tags: windows, readfile

In the unix world, it is a well known gotchya that reading from a file descriptor may succeed and not yield you all the data you asked for. You have to specifically check.

I'm wondering if the same is true in windows.
We're doing synchronous reads, nothing async going on, but we're using the overlapped structure so we can specify and offset and length to read.

This...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx

says:

The ReadFile function returns when one of the following conditions occur:
    The number of bytes requested is read.

and it also says:

If lpOverlapped is not NULL, the read operation starts at the offset that is specified in the OVERLAPPED structure and ReadFile does not return until the read operation is complete. The system updates the OVERLAPPED offset before ReadFile returns.

And it finally says:

The lpNumberOfBytesRead parameter should be set to NULL. Use the GetOverlappedResult function to get the actual number of bytes read.

But what's actually happening is we're getting a successful return but the number of bytes read (from calling GetOverlappedResult) is less than what we asked for.

Nowhere in this documentation does it even imply that could possibly happen, yet it is surely happening.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can ask read more bytes (from offset) than exist in file. in this case count of readed bytes will be less that required in read. this is for file systems. another devices can have another rules. so this is more than possible that count of readed bytes will be less that requested

Comment: It is entirely normal.  Getting as many as you asked for is actually the unusual case, happens only for disk files and then only when the file is large enough.  Devices like serial ports or network sockets only return the data that's currently available in the device driver buffers.  It does block when there is no data at all.  Ultimately it is the device driver that decides this.

Answer (score 0):

This kinda says it all:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150121-00/?p=44863

my favorite quote: "To reduce confusion, the documentation would have been clearer if it hadn't switched terminology midstream."

We are apparently using what they call the "hybrid model."

And the discerning feature of the hybrid model is that it is not well documented, and where it is documented, it is misleading. And nobody seems to have bothered to fix it since 2015.

This is a good example of why you shouldn't try and overload one function to do lots of different things even if at their core, they 'read.'
You make exception upon exception for pipes, and things that have position and things that can be done asynchronously in a synchronous way, and you just end up with a mess. Enter the Win32 api.